# find file with variable name in python script

Tags: python, linux, shell-exec

I am trying to execute the find command in a python script, using a for loop to pass a variable index determining the specific file name to find. I am using the following syntax, which in python returns an empty set, however works in the terminal:

```
for j in [1,2,3,5]:  
    file_name = cmd.getoutput('find . -type f -name "*${j}-xyz.stc" -printf "%f\n"')
```

Obviously, the variable is not being passed to the find expression in my python code, but how can I remedy that? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

variables aren't expanded in python the same as they are in bash.  You probably want:

```
command = r'find . -type f -name "*{0}-xyz.stc" -printf "%f\n"'.format(j)
file_name = cmd.getoutput(command)
```

Also note that the `commands` module is deprecated in favor of `subprocess`.  Finally, it should probably be pointed out that you could write this function in *python* without relying on `find` if you used `os.walk` in conjunction with `glob.glob`.

*untested, but something like this should be close ...*

```
import os
import glob

def find_files(glob_expr):
    for root,_,_ in os.walk(os.curdir):
        for fname in glob.iglob(os.path.join(os.curdir,root,glob_expr)):
            yield fname
for i in (1,2,3,4):
    print (list(find_files('{0}-xyz.stc'.format(i))))
```

Comment: I can't say I understand exactly what you're saying, but your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @user1634460 -- You were trying to expand the variable `j` the way you do in a shell (e.g. `${j}`).  However, that's not how it works in python.  You need to insert special tokens into a string which tell the string how to replace with values.  In this case, `{0}` means to replace that piece of the string with the first value in the corresponding `format` method call.

Comment: @Abuser3.145159 It only works because you aren't trying it with interesting enough inputs -- if the string has double quotes in it, or something that looks like a variable dereference, or (even worse!) something like `$(rm -rf $HOME)` as a substring, it would behave badly. Best practices are to pass an explicit argv array, not a string for interpretation by the shell, which would avoid these bugs.

Answer (score 2):

```
file_name = cmd.getoutput('find . -type f -name "*%i-xyz.stc" -printf "%%f\n"' % (j))
```

Comment: You need to double `%%f` if you want to use old string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Passing filenames in a string to the shell is unsafe (leads to potentially security-impacting bugs). Best practice is to pass an explicit `argv` list:

```
import subprocess
for j in range(1, 6):
    file_name = subprocess.check_output(['find', '.', '-type', 'f', '-name',
                                         '*%s-xyz.stc' % (j,),
                                         '-printf', '%f\\n'])
```

If you *really* care about correctness (and you should!), use `'%f\\0'` as your format string, and expect your outputs to be NUL-separated. Otherwise, you can't tell the difference between a file with a newline in its name and two files returned.

To appreciate the importance, consider the case where an attacker can persuade software running on your system to create a file named like so:

```
/your/top/dir/$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/1-xyz.stc
```

If you treat each line returned by find as a filename, you would consider `/etc/passwd` to be part of your returned values -- a very bad thing if you then present this data to the user, delete it, etc.

Comment: +1 for providing the `subprocess` solution that I was too lazy to come up with ... (I couldn't remember the name of `check_output`)

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thank you. In theory I do care about correctness, but in practice I am just trying to get something pretty menial done. It's taken me some years to do these things comfortably with Matlab, but now I am going gray trying to use Python, because somebody decided it would be a good idea....